# Set meta_key and meta_value for all registered user in wordpress using sql query

Tags: mysql, user-meta, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add  **meta_key** and **meta_value** for the all already registered user in my database via phpmyadmin.

I want:
**meta_key = is_activated**
and **meta_value = 1**
[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in functions.php. visit your site you, it will automatic add/update all user meta value. After executing this code just comment out or remove this code.

```
$args = array(
  'fields'       => 'all',
 );
$blogusers = get_users( $args);
foreach($blogusers as $key => $user){
  update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'is_activated', 1 );
}
```

**OR**
you can also do this using $wpdb

```
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users" );
if( $users ) {
  foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'is_activated', 1 );
  }
}
```

check PHPMyAdmin you will find every user meta_key=is_activated
is set to 1.

Comment: Many Thanks. I used your first code.It works fine.